# How to prevent child sortables from cloning

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have three sortable list boxes, one grey and two yellow. I can drag and clone child sortable li's into the bottom yellow lists no problem.

The problem is that once the child clone li's from the grey list box are placed into the yellow list boxes, you can no longer drag/shift them within the containing yellow list box or to the adjacent yellow list box. They just clone continuously when you attempt to drag them elsewhere.

I would like to drag and clone sortables from the grey list box into the yellow boxes and have the cloned child li's be able to drag and move within the yellow lists boxes without cloning.

How can I prevent the child li's from cloning. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/equiroga/96hJj/

```
$(function() {
   $(".sortable").sortable(
   {  
      helper      : "clone",
      connectWith : ".sortable",

      start       : function(event,ui)
   {
     $(ui.item).show();
     clone    = $(ui.item).clone();
     before   = $(ui.item).prev();
     position = $(ui.item).index();
  },
     beforeStop  : function(event, ui)
   {
     if($(ui.item).closest('ul#sortable1').length>0)
     $(this).sortable('cancel');                                 
   },
     stop        : function(event, ui)
   {
     if (position == 0) $("#sortable1").prepend(clone);
     else before.after(clone);
   }
   });

     $(".sortable").sortable();
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a particular behavior for the first list and a different for the others, the others can't interact with the first using a `coonectWith` selector with [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector.

Code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#sortable1").sortable({
        helper: "clone",
        connectWith: ".sortable",

        start: function (event, ui) {
            $(ui.item).show();
            clone = $(ui.item).clone();
            before = $(ui.item).prev();
            position = $(ui.item).index();
        },
        beforeStop: function (event, ui) {
            if ($(ui.item).closest('ul#sortable1').length > 0) $(this).sortable('cancel');
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            if (position == 0) $("#sortable1").prepend(clone);
            else before.after(clone);
        }
    });

    $(".sortable").sortable({connectWith: ".sortable:not('#sortable1')"});
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/923VG/

Comment: @Edward, Thanks you! it worked like a charm! I guess the only question I have now is how can I change the color of the parent li (li's in grey box) to indicate they have been dragged to the bottom yellow divs. I attempted a toggleClass but to no avail. Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.